# SpringBoot, AOP and tests: ok in Eclipse, but it fail in Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, aspectj, spring-aop, aspectj-maven-plugin

I beg for your help. For my project, https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib, module jobkit, I can't pass 4 tests who pretend to validate calls via @Aspect.

Ok with Eclipse (the last version). Ko with Maven, the last version too.

How to reproduce:

```
   git clone https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib
   git checkout issue51
   mvn install -DskipTests && mvn test -rf :jobkit
   # or just mvn test
```

On class: https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/jobkit/springboot-service/src/test/java/tv/hd3g/jobkit/mod/component/SupervisableAspectTest.java#L70

```
void testWithDefaultName() throws Exception {
        when(supervisableServiceSupplier.createAndStart("TestWithSupervisable.aSupervisableMethod"))
                .thenReturn(supervisable);

        testWithSupervisable.aSupervisableMethod(runnableWithException);
        verify(runnableWithException, times(1)).run(); //OK
        verify(supervisableServiceSupplier, times(1)).createAndStart("TestWithSupervisable.aSupervisableMethod"); // KO
        verify(supervisableServiceSupplier, times(1)).end(supervisable, Optional.empty());
}
```

Aspect class: https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/jobkit/springboot-service/src/main/java/tv/hd3g/jobkit/mod/component/SupervisableAspect.java

```
    @Around("annotationWithSupervisable()")
    public Object manageSupervisable(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        /* [...] */
        // THIS code run with Eclipse Test, but not with Maven... WHY ?
        [...]
        final var supervisable = supervisableServiceSupplier.createAndStart(jobName);
            final var result = joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
            supervisableServiceSupplier.end(supervisable, Optional.empty());
            return result;
        [...]
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(tv.hd3g.jobkit.WithSupervisable)")
    public void annotationWithSupervisable() {
    }
```

Class to "aspect" as test: https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/jobkit/springboot-service/src/test/java/tv/hd3g/jobkit/mod/component/TestWithSupervisable.java

```
@Component
public class TestWithSupervisable {

    @WithSupervisable
    void aSupervisableMethod(final RunnableWithException toTest) throws Exception {
        toTest.run();
    }

[...]
```

You can see the error https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/pull/52

```
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   SupervisableAspectTest.testWithDefaultName:76
Wanted but not invoked:
getSupervisableSupplier bean.createAndStart(
    "TestWithSupervisable.aSupervisableMethod"
);
-> at tv.hd3g.jobkit.engine.SupervisableServiceSupplier.createAndStart(SupervisableServiceSupplier.java:31)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

See the main pom: https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/pom.xml and project pom https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/jobkit/springboot-service/pom.xml

See the THIRD-PARTY.txt file to know the deps versions (all seem the lasts, too): https://github.com/hdsdi3g/prodlib/blob/issue51/jobkit/springboot-service/THIRD-PARTY.txt

Thanks for you help, or ideas!

---

All is working fine in Eclipse, but not in Maven test (surefire).

I want to know if my code/approach is wrong, or if my maven setup/pom is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test also fails in the IDE, if you run it together in the same session with `SupervisableServiceSupplierTest` in this order:

1. `SupervisableServiceSupplierTest`
2. `SupervisableAspectTest`

Calling `sss.end` in the first test like this fixes the problem:

```java
@AfterEach
void end() {
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(supervisableManager, supervisable, exception);
  sss.end(supervisable, Optional.empty());
}
```

This is a classical case of a test not cleaning up a fixture, bleeding over context to another test. It has nothing to do with Maven at all.

P.S.: **Your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link was key** for me to solve this case. You did yourself the greatest favour by providing it. Every newbie and many more experienced developers here can learn from this. Without a complete, reproducible example nobody would have had the slightest chance to debug this and provide a correct answer with the information given in the question as such, because like so often

- someone trying to help needs to see for himself and play around with the code a bit,
- the problem was in the code **not** shown in the question.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks kriegaex ! That's so clever, and this is the only solution to this problem. Indeed this problem was very simple, but i never would have thought of this cause...

Yep, this is a free/OSS project, I share like that without necessarily claiming to create a community around, and it is thanks to this, indeed, that you were able to find the solution, in addition to the amount of testing and tools that I put around.

Comment: I knew that I should always be wary of uses around ThreadLocal, next time I'll be even more careful!